# Is there a mobile app where you can read manga as well as watch anime from?

Tags: resources

I guess the question is as detailed as it can get:
I'm looking for a legal mobile app where you can read manga as well as watch anime from.

Looking forward for your answers.

Comment: Not sure if this is on topic here or not. For anime-watching a number of (legal) sites also have mobile apps. Same goes with manga reading (e.g. Viz media has an app).

Comment: Which platform? Android, iThing, Windows Phone?

Comment: This would probably go well on [software recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I don't think anyone can help you as any site seems illegal on this site. I was trying to help and I got downvoted and I was pretty sure the sites were legal. No wonder this is only a beta site.

Comment: @MiharuDante both you and the downvoter can't be sure, so better do what you can and leave the rest up to mods.

Comment: @MiharuDante The site you linked to was indeed illegal. We decided we'd avoid linking to such sites in order to maintain a more professional feeling/look on our site, so that we're not just another Yahoo! Answers. In any case, if you ever feel a link you provided was wrongly deleted, you can drop by our chat room or create a meta post on it. As for the beta site thing, we're actually on our way to being launched as a "graduated" site. You can even contribute with your opinion [here](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/q/135/49) and [here](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/q/848/49).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can read manga and watch anime with Crunchyroll on Android. The anime app can be used by free members ad-supported, or by paid members ad-free. The manga app however is exclusively for paid members

[CR Manga App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.crunchyroll.crmanga) , 
[CR Anime/Drama App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.crunchyroll.crunchyroid&hl=en)

Similarly for iOS:

[CR Manga App](https://itunes.apple.com/ie/app/manga-by-crunchyroll/id617048063?mt=8) ,
[CR Anime/Drama App](https://itunes.apple.com/ie/app/crunchyroll-watch-anime-drama/id329913454?mt=8)

Windows Phone:

(No Manga App) , [CR Anime/Drama App](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-ie/store/app/crunchyroll/8ce587a5-3277-4e1f-a120-58eb220297d1)

Most apps have anime and manga separate, presumably for development purposes (It's arguably easier to have them separate). I don't think there are any apps (for Android at least) that combine the two in one app.

As far as news apps for anime go, Crunchyroll have [one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.crunchyroll.crnews). But I came across [Daily Anime News](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=florian.baierl.daily_anime_news&hl=en), which compiles several different news sites in one place. (Both Android)

Comment: I definitely like this one and thanks for the info. I was hoping a mobile app that serves as a one-stop shop for anime and manga or even news updates.

Comment: You didn't mention news updates in your original question, but I went ahead and added another one to the list for you ^_^

Comment: Well, Crunchyroll's only lets free accounts watch shows over wi-fi (or did - I have a premium account now).  And still had the 1-week delay, plus ads.  Dunno about their manga app.

Comment: Their manga in general is premium only as far as i know

Answer (score 3):

According to [this piece of news](http://en.rocketnews24.com/2014/03/05/new-online-manga-service-features-200-titles-three-selectable-languages-and-no-fees/), there will be a new service starting from March 22nd 2014 called [ComicWalker](http://comic-walker.com/).

It'll be completely free of charge, and will have around 200 manga titles initially available, of which about 40 will be translated into English.
The full and official list will be available on the same day the service is launched.

The first link provides some more details about the availability of the content, as well as the languages available.

#### Update

As of April 29th 2014, the site features 163 titles in Japanese, 33 in English and 35 in Chinese. See the full list [here](http://comic-walker.com/contents/list/) (switch between languages at the top right).

Also, besides the iOS and Android apps, you can also view the content on your PC browser.

Comment: Great site -- looks like they have a decent selection. I would note that they only have translations in traditional Chinese characters, which would make  it difficult for idiots like me who can't read them to actually take advantage of the titles there.

Comment: @Maroon No, you can actually switch between languages in the top right corner of the page. They have titles available in Japanese, Chinese and English.

Comment: No, what I meant was that they only use a specific set of Chinese characters (the type not used in China proper) for their Chinese offerings, which might be less user friendly than your description suggests.

Answer (score 1):

Legality is the key issue. You can find many legal anime-hosting sites: VizAnime, Crunchyroll, etc., but manga? Much of the time it is meant for print or through subscription-based digital viewing, not for free. That being said, there are multitudes of manga reading apps, illegal though.

Answer (score 0):

Crunchyroll has a number of apps available for streaming anime and reading manga. It is legal, though you may have to be a "Premium Member" (monthly subscription) to access content on the mobile apps. There are also some region restrictions, but most of their catalog is available to users in the US.

Here is a of platforms they have apps for.
http://www.crunchyroll.com/devices